# JQuery - Wait for two iframes to load

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a button that loads two different pages in two iframes.  I need to wait for those loads to complete (like ready(), don't care about images and other content) and then trigger another action.  How can I do this?

Comment: Is this an AJAX load? If yes then what AJAX library do you use?

Comment: No, not AJAX.  One is a form.submit() and the other I'm just setting the src attribute of the iframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be for the iFrame content to signal that it is ready. Here is a simplistic way to do this:

**Main Page**

```
var status = [false, false];

function doneLoading(index)
{
   status[index] = true;
   if (status[1] && status[2])
      alert("Both iframes are done loading");
}
```

**In each iFrame**

```
$(document).ready(function() { parent.doneLoading(1) }); // or 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the pages that are being loaded in the iframes.

Comment: You can use the same approach. Just attach an onload event handler to each iframe. $("#iframe1").load(function() { doneLoading(1) });

Comment: You set [0] and [1] to false, then use [1] and [2]. This is JS so [2] == false anyway. Flawed code and no waiting/callback mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Using [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) will help you (jQuery 1.5 and higher). 
For example:

```
function doAjax(){
   return $.get('foo.htm');
}

function doMoreAjax(){
   return $.get('bar.htm');
}

$.when( doAjax(), doMoreAjax() )
   .then(function(){
      console.log( 'I fire once BOTH ajax requests have completed!' );
   })
   .fail(function(){
      console.log( 'I fire if one or more requests failed.' );
   });
```

Comment: he specified that is NOT AJAX

Comment: Nice catch (y) But clarification that it's not ajax was added 15 minutes later after I've posted this answer.. a year ago

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the safest solution might be to have a parent iframe that would embedd both iframes and wait for the entire page (the parent page) to load :

```
$(parent).load(function(){
   ... //if you get there then the 2 iframes are already loaded
}
```

The drawback is that it's a lot of iframes