# Do something AFTER the page has loaded completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm using some embed codes that insert HTML to the page dynamically and since I have to modify that dynamically inserted HTML, I want a jquery function to wait until the page has loaded, I tried `delay` but it doesnt seem to work.

So for example, the dynamically inserted HTMl has an element `div#abc`

and I have this jquery:

```
if ( $('#abc')[0] ) { 
  alert("yes");
}
```

the alert doesn't show up.

I'd appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Depends on where/how you are inserting the dynamic html that has div#abc

Comment: How is the `div#abc` added to the HTML/DOM?

Comment: Hmm.. for example the google plus one embed code, I place a javascript in my html, which in turn loads an iframe and other divs, I want to modify one of THOSE elements

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    ....
});
```

If you have to wait for an iframe (and don't care about the assets, just the DOM) - try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('iframe').load(function() { 
       // do something
    });
});
```

Comment: could it be because the embed code insert html in an iframe and/or asynchronously?

Comment: This waits for all the assets on CURRENT page. Do you have iframes to wait for as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly, not just the current page

Comment: Updated the answer for an iframe

Comment: still no alert, cause the iframe is not present in the current page either, its added via javascript through that embed code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315065/jquery-wait-for-two-iframes-to-load - maybe that will help?

Comment: If you know a way that works for CSS assets too? I mean it may take a more time images and fonts included in CSS download, but the .load() function just sees if all page loaded (not the CSS assets I think)

Comment: Consider that `load()` method is deprecated in newer versions and could cause errors in console. If you face that issue, use `on('load',function(){ })` instead.

Answer (score 10):

That is the purpose of [jQuery's `.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('#abc').length ) //If checking if the element exists, use .length
        alert("yes");
});
```

> ***Description***: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully
>   loaded.

Comment: James has it right.  Check out the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

..the DOM will be loaded and ready for manipulation when this is called.

Comment: And just as a quick note...I believe the difference between a window.load and a jQuery.ready is that window.load waits until *all* assets (e.g. stylesheets, images, etc) have been downloaded before it is called while jQuery.ready fires as soon as the DOM is loaded and doesn't care if images and such are still loading.

Comment: "embed codes that insert HTML to the page dynamically" can very well be added to the DOM after the `ready` event is triggered.

Answer (score 7):

Using the [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) should be enough. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //your code here
});
```

or

```
$(function(){

});
```

which is a shortcut of the first.

Answer (score 7):

The `load()` method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8 and removed in version 3.0.
So you have to use -

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
 // code here
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers. Give an explanation to why this code snippet would work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ( $('#abc')[0] ) { 
      alert("yes");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, to handle my JQuery before or after page loads, will use:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // use jQuery code here with $ formatting
    // executes BEFORE page finishes loading
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // use jQuery code here with $ formatting
    // executes AFTER page finishes loading
});
```

---

## ES6 Update

Here's the ES6 version of the script using the arrow function:

```
// Executes before page finishes loading.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Use JavaScript code here.
});
```

In the first example, we use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to execute the code when the HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed.

```
// Executes after page finishes loading.
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Use JavaScript code here.
});
```

In the second example, we use the `load` event to execute the code after all page content has been loaded, including images and other external resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function () { ... }
```

can be enough but otherwise your embeded code (what ever that can be) might provide some callback functionality that you can make use of.

[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay) should only be used to delay [animations](http://api.jquery.com/animate).

Comment: `load()` is deprecated after jquery 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Make sue you bind the event with dom load so it's there when trigger called.
This is how you do it. Hope this helps someone someday

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
   //enter code here
   $("#dropdow-id").trigger('change');
});`
```