# How to Load all fetch from react before loading custom javascript from separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom, fetch

I am using both react and jquery separately I want bundle.js from react to fetch all api data before running jquery functions.

I have a react code loading all the images from servers / api and jquery to slide those images and managing height of the image to fit screen.
I have first included bundle.js and then my custom.js file. Even though bundle.js runs first, but fetch api runs after custom.js due to which jquery is not able to slide those images.

App.js

```
export class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        loading : false,
        all_data : []
    }
    this.fetchFromServer();
}

fetchFromServer(){
    Promise.all([
        fetch("http://abcdef.com/api/slider.php",{
            method : "POST",
            headers: new Headers({
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
            }),
            body: JSON.stringify({
                limit : "10",
            })
        })
    ]).then(([all_post_api])=>Promise.all([all_post_api.json()])).
    then(([post_data]) => this.setState({
        loading : false,
        all_data : post_data
    }))
}

render(){
        const allowRender = this.state.all_data && this.state.all_data.carousel
        if (allowRender) {

        return (<div className="right-content">

            <Main data={this.state.all_data} />
        </div>)

        } 

        return null;
}
```

}

Main.js

```
export class Main extends Component {

render(){
    console.log(this.props.data.carousel);
    return (


                <div className="flexslider home-page">
                    <ul className="slides">
                    {
                        this.props.data.carousel.map((name,index)=>{
                            return (
                            <li className="images-bg" key={index}>
                                <img src={name.url} />
                                <div className="circle">
                                            <div className="home-title left">
                                                <span>
                                                    Welcome <strong>to</strong>
                                                </span>
                                                <span>
                                                    <strong>foto</strong>hunter
                                                </span>
                                                <p>Only the best pictures of animals and travel.</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <a className="button-down glyph fa-angle-down" href=""></a>
                                        </div>
                            </li>
                            )

                        })

                    }
                    </ul>
                </div>




    )
}

}
```

custom.js

```
$(function (){        
 console.log("loaded content");
$('.images-bg').each(function(){
            $(this).css({
                'background-image': 'url(' +$('img', this).hide().attr('src') +')',
                'height': $(window).height()
            });
        });

        /*----------  BIG SLIDER  ----------*/
        $('.portfolio-with-details .flexslider, .service .flexslider').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 5000});
        $('.portfolio-image.flexslider').flexslider({slideshow: false});
        $('.flexslider.home-page').flexslider({
            slideshowSpeed: 5000,
            after : function(slider){
                var next = $('.flex-active-slide', slider).find('.home-title');
                var className = '';
                if(next.hasClass('left')){
                    className = 'bounceInLeft';
                }else if(next.hasClass('top')){
                    className = 'flipInX';
                }else if(next.hasClass('zoom')){
                    className = 'bounceIn';
                }
                next.addClass(className + ' animated');
                next.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                    next.removeClass(className + ' animated');
                });
            }
        });
        /*----------  //BIG SLIDER  ----------*/

    })
```

Below screenshot is what i am getting now. I want opposite. I expected custom.js console.log message to  print after Main.js console.log

[image: console log image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Jquery try changing it to

```
$( document ).ready(function (){        
 console.log("loaded content");
$('.images-bg').each(function(){
            $(this).css({
                'background-image': 'url(' +$('img', this).hide().attr('src') +')',
                'height': $(window).height()
            });
        });

        /*----------  BIG SLIDER  ----------*/
        $('.portfolio-with-details .flexslider, .service .flexslider').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 5000});
        $('.portfolio-image.flexslider').flexslider({slideshow: false});
        $('.flexslider.home-page').flexslider({
            slideshowSpeed: 5000,
            after : function(slider){
                var next = $('.flex-active-slide', slider).find('.home-title');
                var className = '';
                if(next.hasClass('left')){
                    className = 'bounceInLeft';
                }else if(next.hasClass('top')){
                    className = 'flipInX';
                }else if(next.hasClass('zoom')){
                    className = 'bounceIn';
                }
                next.addClass(className + ' animated');
                next.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                    next.removeClass(className + ' animated');
                });
            }
        });
        /*----------  //BIG SLIDER  ----------*/

    })
```

This way, React fetches before mounting and Jquery fires when page is fully ready!

Comment: Even using componentWillMount results same output.
What I want is 
"loaded content" should be printed after {carousel: Array(3)}

Comment: Still, in your position, I would try to convert your Jquery to React. It leads to less problems. Hope this solution works though

Comment: I got same result even with above changes. However, on construction I had my loading state false but inside componentWillMount I changed loading to true and than used fetchFromServer() method, 

result was 
Loading : true, {}
Read! (from jquery)
Loading: false, {Carousel:Array(3)}

why all_data state didn't changed any idea ?

Comment: try to remove the componentwillmount and check this for your jquery
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036969/do-something-after-the-page-has-loaded-completely

Comment: I am trying to convert my Jquery to react for the moment. Lets see it this works or not

Comment: It's better, trust me. React ha its own lifecycle methods, When you mix it with Jquery you can have a really bad time