# Click link inside dynamic iframe from parent document using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, hyperlink

I have a page with a dynamically added iframe, the iframe body has a link in it.

How can I use jquery on the parent page, with the click() function, to click the link in the iframe that only appears after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in the same domain, then it may not be possible to due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you are in the same domain,

```
$('#iFrameID').contents().find('#linkID').click();
```

should work. Hopefully what that code is doing is self explainitory.

If you are not in the same domain, you can 'spoof' the HTML into your own domain. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) for.. well basically this question actually.

**EDIT:**

The question is actually "how do I access the iFrame once it is loaded?"

You need some sort of calling function for when the page in the iFrame loads. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315065/jquery-wait-for-two-iframes-to-load) for some examples.

Comment: I didn't originally describe the situation well, I have edited the question.